# Providing update notification from DomainService to DomainContext

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, .net-4.0, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

I need to inform the DomainContext in the silverlight application about changes that are made on the serverside (aka. Model of the DomainService).

Does the DomainService or other classes for RIA Services provide such notification (like Events) or do i have to call a method on the DomainService periodically to check if changes where made to the Model?

Or is there any other solution that is best-practise to notify the DomainContext about changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already considered using [WCF Callbacks](http://www.google.com/search?q=silverlight+WCF+callbacks)?